# Proper way to listen to NSNotifications

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, nsnotification

Is it proper, if I have 2 notifications on a view controller to have 2 observers like so:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotifications:) name:@"note1" object:nil];
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotifications:) name:@"note2" object:nil];
```

Or do I just figure out which notification was run by passing in nil to the name and then checking the notification sent in the handleNotification function:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotifications:) name:nil object:nil];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if you pass `nil` as a name, you'll receive all notifications regardless of their name (not just the two you want). It's better to subscribe to each one separately, by naming them.

Excerpt from Apple documentation:

> If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s name to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

(That point was, at first, not clear to me and I misread it by thinking you would not receive any notification).

You can use the same callback/listener for both, and decide what to do based on the notification received.

You could create a category on `NSNotificationCenter` to handle the registration of multiple names, that's what categories are made for!

Comment: Passing `nil` to the notification name parameter will actually listen to *all* notifications. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDCIGGB

Comment: nil listens to all the dozens of notifications that you have not the slightest interest in, so I'd say it's a bad idea. Especially if you do this with one observer, you'd likely do it with all observers. So suddenly each of 100 notifications is sent to 100 observers who compare the name with the one that they care about and it gets very inefficient.

Comment: Very good point, as a string comparison is not a cheap operation (even when notification names are `const`).